# Sending File in mail in a loop

Tags: java, multithreading, email

I have requirement like to send a different xls files to different email.
So I have created one loop in which I'm performing two action

1) Creation of file in temp
2) attache this file to mail message and send it across.

My problem is File is created successfully but I'm getting blank file without data in xls.

My code to generate file is as below,

```
//in a for loop
    fos = new FileOutputStream(path1);
                    wb.write(fos); //I think writing is in progress and while file is sent in mail hence getting blank

                    destination = new File(path1);
                    InternetAddress to = null;


                to = new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com",StringPool.BLANK);
                MailMessage message=new MailMessage(to,to, "temp", createEmailBody(email,numberOfuser), true);
                message.addFileAttachment(destination);
                MailServiceUtil.sendEmail(message);
```

Comment: i don't really see you add anything to fos, so ... what exactly did you expect?

Comment: You need to close the stream at the very least. That should flush all your data to the underlying file system.

Answer (score 0):

Do `wb.flush()` and `wb.close()` before sending and set a break point to check if the file is written before sending it. Hope it help.